# Nested list from list using list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have the following `list` called `flat`:

```
flat= ['11','13', '17', '19', '13', '17', '19','22','35','14','15']
```

I splitted it into a `list` of `tuples` using `zip` function as

```
list(zip(flat[0::2], flat[1::2]))
```

with the following output:

```
[('11', '13'), ('17', '19'), ('13', '17'), ('19', '22'), ('35', '14')]
```

Now, how to convert the list `flat` into the following result using list comprehension?

```
[['11', '13'], ['17', '19'], ['13', '17'], ['19', '22'], ['35', '14']]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1:** Without list Comprehension

You need to `map` `zip` object to `list`:

```
list(map(list,zip(flat[0::2], flat[1::2])))

[['11', '13'], ['17', '19'], ['13', '17'], ['19', '22'], ['35', '14']]
```

**Method 2** Using list comprehension:

```
[list(l) for l in zip(flat[0::2], flat[1::2])]

[['11', '13'], ['17', '19'], ['13', '17'], ['19', '22'], ['35', '14']]
```

Or:

```
[[l1,l2] for l1,l2 in zip(flat[0::2], flat[1::2])]

[['11', '13'], ['17', '19'], ['13', '17'], ['19', '22'], ['35', '14']]
```

Comment: This is not the best solution. It gets close to what should be done. But, definitely, duplicating the list twice is a bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

A pure list comprehension approach:

```
[[flat[a], flat[a+1]] for a in range(0, len(flat)-2, 2)]
```

Here `range(0, len(flat)-2, 2)` allows iteration through the indices of the flat array in steps of two, and `[flat[a], flat[a+1]]` gets a pair of elements as a list. This approach will fail if the orginal list has a length which is not a multiple of 2.

Answer (score 1):

Using a list comprehension you could use:

```
[[flat[i], flat[i+1]] for i in range(0, len(flat)-1, 2)]
```

which yields

```
[['11', '13'], ['17', '19'], ['13', '17'], ['19', '22'], ['35', '14']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using itertools for avoiding duplicating the list twice:

```
import itertools

flat= ['11','13', '17', '19', '13', '17', '19','22','35','14','15']

result = list(
  map(list,
      zip(
        itertools.islice(flat, 0, len(flat), 2),
        itertools.islice(flat, 1, len(flat), 2)
      )
  )
)
print(result)
```

or use `iter`:

```
it = iter(flat)
[[x, y] for x, y in zip(it, it)]
```

Here you have the [live example](https://repl.it/repls/UnacceptableBeautifulDemand)

The tests with `timeit` report that the `iter` solution with the list comprehension are the better aproaches:

```
import itertools

flat= ['11','13', '17', '19', '13', '17', '19','22','35','14','15']

def lcomprehension_aproach(flat):
  return [[flat[a], flat[a+1]] for a in range(0, len(flat)-2, 2)]

def itertools_aproach(flat):
  result = list(
    map(list,
        zip(
          itertools.islice(flat, 0, len(flat), 2),
          itertools.islice(flat, 1, len(flat), 2)
        )
    )
  )
  return result

def iter_aproach(flat):
  it = iter(flat)
  return [[x, y] for x, y in zip(it, it)]

print(lcomprehension_aproach(flat))
print(itertools_aproach(flat))  
print(iter_aproach(flat))

from timeit import timeit

print(timeit("lcomprehension_aproach(flat)", globals=globals()))
print(timeit("itertools_aproach(flat)",      globals=globals()))
print(timeit("iter_aproach(flat)",           globals=globals()))
```

> 5.122298364993185 // list comprehension time (Jack Aidley solution)
>
> 8.221981940994738 // itertools time
>
> 3.757848952009226 // itert + comprehension time